# How to perform touch using the accessibility in android

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibility

I want to perform the touch functionality. i.e., i have to touch the another app seekbar from my app. Please any one help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find an AccessibilityNodeInfo corresponding to the Node in the view hierarchy that you want to click. Once you have that node you can call performAction

```
node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
```

That will dispatch a click action as you'd expect. AccessibilityNodeInfo#isClickable can be a helpful way to ensure the node you're interacting with should accept a click and do something with it.

Comment: Note that as the name suggests, this will perform a click action and not touch action. If the given node does not handle click but does handle touch, then this action will not do anything.